# Fastest way of solving polynomial associated with projection to a unit simplex

Tags: polynomials, optimization

In Professor Boyd [homework solution](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364b/hw4sol.pdf), one needs to solve the following which is a polynomial of $\nu$ to find $\nu^*$:
$$
g(\nu)=\frac{1}{2}\|(\mathbf{x}-\nu \mathbf{1})_{-}\|^2+v(\mathbf{1}^{\top}x-1)-n\nu^2
$$

1. How do I know this function is a concave function?
2. How do I know it has a unique global maximizer?
3. If the answer to the above questions are yes, is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) algorithm on WikiPedia is the fastest way of solving it or there is another way that uses the structure of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The non-linear terms of the expression occur in half the sum over
   $$
   (x_k-ν)_-^2-2ν^2=(ν-x_k)_+^2-2ν^2,
   $$
   using $u_-=\min(0,u)=-\max(0,-u)=-(-u)_+$. This is concave for $x_k>ν$ as well as for $x_x<ν$.

   The sum of concave and linear functions is again concave.
2. The single functions are even strictly concave due to the factor 2, and so is their sum. As there are no linear segments, the maximum is unique. There is a maximum as $\nu^2\to\infty$ for $\nu\to\pm\infty$.
3. No, bisection is always the worst case. You can do better by taking 3 points, build a quadratic model, compute its maximum and retain the 3 points around the new maximal value. Apply anti-stalling tricks like in the Illinois variant of the false position method.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you got the equality you mentioned and how does this shows the solution is unique? Also, I appreciated you addressed my question, but it would be great if you answer my questions by ordering them as they come in the statement.